# Path where Firefox Mobile Addons store their data?

Tags: file-system, firefox-for-android, browser-add-ons

I've installed Firefox Mobile on my Asus eee transformer and installed the scriptish add-on for using some userscripts.

Some of them require editing. The problem is I don't know which path contains these scripts.

Does anyone here know that? Or know where the firefox data is stored?

Answer (score 2):

As with all apps, they store their data below the `/data/data` directory, in a directory named according to their package name -- which is what you can see following the "id=" in the playstore URL. So for Firefox, data should be in `/data/data/org.mozilla.firefox`.

So far the good news. Now for the bad news: This directory can only be accessed by the app itself -- or by the root user. So if your device is not rooted: bad luck.

I could imagine that for userscripts and some other profile data, Firefox *might* (or might not) use some storage on the sdcard -- so you could check if you see a similar directory structure there. Certainly not with the "doubled" `/data`, and maybe even just named "firefox" -- as I do not have Firefox installed, I cannot check, but it's worth a look.

Comment: The good news is that Firefox have a very basic file browser and so you can open the URL `file:///data/data/org.mozilla.firefox/` from Firefox itself without rooting.

Answer (score 0):

As Izzy says, all the data are in `/data/data/org.mozilla.firefox`, which means you can only read them if your device is rooted. Inside that directory, the path `files/mozilla` has a very similar layout to your `~/.mozilla/firefox` directory on a Linux desktop: it has a `profiles.ini` and a directory `asdf12yz.default` containing all the interesting files.